# How do I navigate through the website https://www.hinduscriptures.in/?

Tags: discussion

I am interested in reading the various Puranas. I have pdf files of a few Puranas, namely the *Markendeya Purana*, *Kalki Purana*, and the *Shrimad Bhagavatam*. In this stack exchange post ([Are there any other Puranas that predict Adi Shanakaracharya besides the Bhavishya Purana?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/14738/are-there-any-other-puranas-that-predict-adi-shanakaracharya-besides-the-bhavish)) I found a link to the 30th chapter of the *Kurma Purana*. The link is given by the following: https://www.hinduscriptures.in/Content/Articles/PDFs/30601/79_chapter_30.pdf.

I visited the site  https://www.hinduscriptures.in, but I am unable to find pdf documents of the Puranas. I also tried truncating the link to no avail. For instance, I entered https://www.hinduscriptures.in/Content/Articles/PDFs but received the following message:

> > "403 - Forbidden: Access is denied.
> > You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied."

What should I do? How should I navigate this website to get access to the pdfs? Please kindly let me know.

Comment: Go to https://www.hinduscriptures.in/scriptures/puranas-18-puranas-mahapurana then click on the purana name and chapter number [from left navigation section].. though this looks off topic here..

Comment: @YDS Thank you!!!!

Comment: @SwiftPushkar I will post similar questions in Meta next time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can read the puranas from hinduscriptures website by navigating to https://www.hinduscriptures.in/scriptures/puranas-18-puranas-mahapurana and then click on the purana name and then chapter number [from left navigation section].